# Eliminate duplicate entries in Hibernate tables of one-to-many relationship reference

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, hibernate, one-to-many

I am currently working with a program that receives three number values (companyName, groupName, hostName) each time you run the program. Each time I received the three values, I grouped them into one object (Datas) and stored them in a List (List).

My goal is to store all the values into a database with three tables (company, group, host).

The three tables are connected: Company is one-to-many with Group and Group is one-to-many with Host.

So I have created three classes (Company.java, Group.java, Host.java) that will take the appropriate values and create new instances of the class using constructor.

Then I would store each instance of the class into the database using hibernate session.

My code goes like this:

```
for (Datas data:Datas){
     Company company = new Company(data.getCompanyName);
     Group group = new Group(company, data.getGroupName);
     Host host = new Host(group, data.getHostName);

     session.save(company);
     session.save(group);
     session.save(host);     
}
```

While the code above does allow me to save all my data to my tables with the correct One-To-Many relationship, it doesn't allow me to prevent duplicates entries.

For example right now my tables store things this way after 5 datas are saved:

```
Company
id (auto-increment)  Name
1                    Google
2                    Google
3                    Google
4                    Yahoo
5                    Yahoo

Group
id (auto-increment)  Company_id  Name
1                    1           HR
2                    2           HR
3                    3           OP
4                    4           HR
5                    5           PR

Host
id (auto-increment)  Group_id  Name
1                    1         Jane
2                    2         Harry
3                    3         Molly
4                    4         Garry
5                    5         Neo
```

While the tables above are technically correct, I really want to eliminate the duplicates.  Right now in the Company table, all the "Google" and "Yahoo" entries are the exact same thing.  On the Group table, the 1st and 2nd entry are the same thing since they both have the name "HR" and they both reference to the company "Google."

This way rather than creating 3 Company entries "Google," we would only create 1.  And all the entries on the Group table would only reference to that entry.  Same logic for the Host table.

Correct tables should look like:

```
Company
id (auto-increment)  Name
1                    Google
2                    Yahoo

Group
id (auto-increment)  Company_id  Name
1                    1           HR
2                    1           OP
3                    2           HR
4                    2           PR

Host
id (auto-increment)  Group_id  Name
1                    1         Jane
2                    1         Harry
3                    3         Molly
4                    4         Garry
5                    5         Neo
```

How do I make such adjustment in my code?  Should I do something with the data before instantiating the three classes? Or should I do something when instantiating with the class constructors? Or is there a Hibernate annotation I could use to prevent such duplication?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your for-loop should basically query the database based on the business natural key values and determine whether a record exists and branch based on that fact.

```
for ( Datas data : datas ) {
  Company company = companyRepository.findByName( data.getCompanyName() );
  if ( company == null ) {
    // new company implies everything else is also new
    company = new Company( data.getCompanyName() );
    group = new Group( company, data.getGroupName() );
    host = new Host( group, data.getHostName() );
    session.save( company );
    session.save( group );
    session.save( host );
  }
  else {
    // since company exists, we need to check whether group/host exist
    Group group = groupRepository.findByName( data.getGroupName() );
    if ( group == null ) {
      // since group doesn't exist, neither will host
      group = new Group( company, data.getGroupName() );
      host = new Host( group, data.getHostName() );
      session.save( group );
      session.save( host );
      // depending on relationships, you may need to link group to company
      // followed by updating company.
    }
    else {
      // group exists, check if host does
      Host host = hostRepository.findByName( data.getHostName() );
      if ( host == null ) {
        // host doesn't, create it.
        host = new Host( group, data.getHostName() );
        session.save( host );
        // depending on relationships, you may need to link host to group
        // followed by updating group.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The various repository classes that expose a `#findByName(String)` method are meant to just illustrate a query which you perform with a predicate that looks for the specified name for the entity.

Obviously if your `Datas` structure carry more detail beyond that of just a name value which also needs to be merged with the existing records, you'll need to add logic to the loop to apply any modifications to the persisted object fetched by the `#findByName(String` methods.

```
// Simplified example for the Host
Host host = hostRepository.findByName( data.getHostName() );
if ( host == null ) {
  host = new Host( group, data.getHostName() );
  host.setSomeOtherAttribute( data.getHostSomeOtherAttribute() );
  session.save( host );
}
else {
  host.setsomeOtherAttribute( data.getHostSomeOtherAttribute() );
  session.update( host );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!